# How to have different values with network.instantiate for different players/clients PUN2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon-pun

I am using photon pun2 network.instantiate to instantiate a gameobject in unity but I want it to have different rotation for different players. Can I use custom argument for this? If yes then how? Or please suggest some other approach.

It is a card game where I want to instantiate a random card which only the player who's turn it is can see and others can only see the back of the card. So I plan to rotate the card while instantiating it for other players.